# Draw this ring chart with d3js

Tags: d3.js, charts

I am new to d3 and I am trying to do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PceY.png). Here is what I have done so far [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hb7rn7xc/), but I don't know how to align the lines to put them like in the picture and also how to put an information box below the chart.

```
var x=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,r]).range([0,w])
var y=d3.scale.linear().domain([r,0]).range([h,0])

center_group.append('line').attr("x1",x(r/4)).attr("y1",0);
center_group.append('line').attr("x1",x(-r/4)).attr("y1",0);
center_group.append('line').attr("x1",0).attr("y1",x(25));
center_group.append('line').attr("x1",0).attr("y1",x(-r/4));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to align the reticle lines within the circle. I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30bdfasa/4/) which should demonstrate a solution to the two issues in your original fiddle.

```
    //circle svg drawn above this point...
    center_group.append('line').attr("x1",x(r/6)).attr("y1",0).attr("x2",x(r/5.1));
    center_group.append('line').attr("x1",x(-r/6)).attr("y1",0).attr("x2",x(-r/5.1));
    center_group.append('line').attr("x1",0).attr("y1",x(19.7)).attr("y2",x(r/6));
    center_group.append('line').attr("x1",0).attr("y1",x(-r/6)).attr("y2",x(-r/5.1));
    //then include table, as shown here: http://bl.ocks.org/gka/17ee676dc59aa752b4e6
```

The first issue is that the lines were being drawn before the (white-filled) circle (so any line within the circle was covered). Second issue was that the lines were unbounded, so i added x2 and y2 attributes where needed. See [picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK8CO.png) for results.

Regarding the information box, you could simply append a text element under the chart and drop your data in there, but for something more robust, you could include a table, as shown in the example linked in my code above (only two links allowed apparently).

Comment: That makes sense! It was getting on my nerves. Thanks! And, last but not least, is that I need to add the graph inside de ring... As shown in the [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4PceY.png)

Comment: ok, I've copy/pasted in the chart code from the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195) and then added a white mask to give it the look. check the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/30bdfasa/4/) You can uncomment the indicated lines to reveal the mask, in case you need to move it around. This solution could be cleaned up quite a bit, but it does seem to serve. Enjoy!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to interpolate the line, as is shown in your picture, but you could add your favorite interpolation with a single line using mike's example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190).